# Declaration terminated Incorrectly?

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, subclass

I have some C++ code and I keep getting that the declaration was terminated incorrectly. I've checked all my statements but see no place where I missed a semicolon. I've looked over my program a billion times but can't find the abnormality. Here's the code.

```
class PizzaFactory
{
    public:
    virtual Pizza* bake() = 0;

};

class CheeseFactory : public PizzaFactory
{
    private:

    public:
    Pizza* bake() override //Declaration terminated incorrectly
    {               
        Dough doe, *newDoe = &doe;
        TomatoSauce ts, *newTS = &ts;
        Cheese chz, *newChz = &chz;


        Pizza myPizza(MAX_TOPS);
        Pizza* newPizza = &myPizza;

        newPizza.add(newDoe);
        newPizza.add(newTS);
        newPizza.add(newChz);

        return newPizza;        
    }

};  //here is where the "Unexpected '}'" is thrown and declaration 
    //terminated 
    //incorrectly
```

The error is given for the line "Pizza* bake() override". It also throws the same error and  "Unexpected '}'" at the last line of code. I don't get it.

Comment: Have you enabled *C++11* support?

Comment: You use and return pointers to local variables, variables which will go out of scope and be destructed as soon as the function `bake` returns.

Comment: I'm using a BCC Compiler that I installed last summer. How could I check if it has C++ 11 support?

Comment: As for your error, the second error is most likely due to the first.

Comment: Error messages from a C++ compiler are what the ***compiler thinks*** the error means. The complexity of C++ means that the actual error might be something completely different. For example, in this case, the error could simply mean a missing forward declaration. But because your question fails to meet pretty much all requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], it's unlikely that there'll be any good answer for you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so should I make a copy of the object and pass it or would that still have an effect and is that why I am getting this error

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what was I supposed to add here. It is minimal. This is the only section of my code that is throwing errors so I thought it was complete. And idk how you would verify header files.

Comment: It's unrelated to the build error. It will lead to *undefined behavior* though. And yes use *value* (objects) instead of pointers. Most of the time it's the right choice.

Comment: @DemarcusSales, Yes, just return `Pizza`. There appears to be no need to use a pointer. It won't even be copied if the compiler is decent.

Comment: It is minimal, but it is not complete. Trying to compile the shown code will result in completely different, unrelated errors. As such, this fails the "complete" and "verifiable" requirements. A [mcve] means anyone can copy and try to compile the shown code themselves, and reproduce **the same exact error**.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik should i post the entire header file?

Comment: No, you should post a [mcve]. Whatever is the minimum amount of code that's required to reliably reproduce the compilation error. If there's nothing else in the header file, then you could post it verbatim. But if there's anything irrelevant there, that has no effect on the compilation error, it is irrelevant and only serves as a distraction, so remove it. Ditto for the existing code, too. Does removing those three `newPizza.add()` calls affect the compilation error? If not, then what exactly did you expect to accomplish by showing them? Remove them, irrelevant. Ditto for everything else.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik lolol okay

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The whole point is I don't know what's causing the error if I did I wouldn't be here tbh. That's simple logic.

Comment: Have you tried compiling without the "override" keyword?

Comment: Everyone, including myself, doesn't "know what's causing the error" the first time it occurs, all the time. More than once I introduced a typo that the compiler didn't choke on until hundreds of lines later, after a massive lambda wrapped inside a template. For starters, experienced programmers do not write a massive pile of code first, then try to compile the whole thing, and then scratch their heads. We write a few lines at a time, then try to compile it, then write more. How many lines of code did you write, before trying to compile the whole thing, and getting this error?

Comment: ... so when I got my compilation error popping out of a chunk of code hundreds of lines away, I knew that since I only changed a few lines of code much earlier, that's where the typo must be.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The problem was my compiler was not up to date thank you for the help. I guess my question was good enough because EdgarRokjan was the only one to give me useful information.